# Ubuntu 16.4 LTS and arm lockout

Tags: nyx

My question evolves around tor arm the controller used with tor. I hope I'm posting in the correct area as I'm not at all sure where the fault lies; either with Ubuntu or arm. If I'm in the wrong place apologies!

My relay has been in operation for little better than two weeks. I am new to tor relay. I've experienced the same problem several times. For the most part the relay takes care of itself with me checking it's operation periodically throughout the day. Until it happens.. I lose all Administrative functions with arm. Meanwhile, the relay seemingly continues to function as normal. The only solution I've found so far is to stop tor, and arm and do a hard restart. It's then good again for who knows how long until it happens again.

I've intentionally left out computer specifics as the computer itself is not the issue. It's software related either arm or Ubuntu OR both. How to sort it out, I am at a loss.

Thanks for any help everyone :-)

Adri

Upon further exploration!

From notices.log

```
Oct 29 04:31:51.000 [notice] Circuit handshake stats since last time: 90/90 TAP, 1/1 NTor.
Oct 29 04:31:51.000 [notice] Since startup, we have initiated 0 v1 connections, 0 v2 connections, 0 v3 connections, and 1820 v4 connections; and received 746 v1 connections, 315 v2 connections, 380 v3 connections, and 5426 v4 connections.
Oct 29 07:35:02.000 [notice] *Received reload signal (hup)*. Reloading config and resetting internal state.
Oct 29 07:35:02.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Oct 29 07:35:02.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
```

So why am I getting a "reload signal??"

Answer (score 0):

It's a startup scripts that are causing this - they're used to send sighup or even make a full reload if the service is failed to respond or send a heartbeat to systemd, stuff happens. In case of systemd - find tor's unit definition in `/etc/systemd` and check these values:

```
TimeoutSec=5m
Restart=always
WatchdogSec=3m
```

and do `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: There was no reference at all to tor in systemd. Now what? Adri

Comment: @adriann `systemctl list-unit-files` has no mention? when tor is running - please send `ps ax | grep tor` output and attach your torrc config - we will take a look

Answer (score 0):

One source for a reload signal is likely to be the `logrotate` daemon.

If you look at the script in `/etc/logrotate.d/tor` you'll see that part of it's process is calling `service tor reload`. This is used to get Tor to append to the newly created log files, after the old ones have been moved to `.1`, `.2`, etc.

It shouldn't stop Tor from running, but it might interrupt your connection to the control port, simply exiting and restarting `arm` should resolve that without restarting Tor.

Comment: daily
 rotate 5
 compress
 delaycompress
 missingok
 notifempty
 create 0640 debian-tor adm
 sharedscripts
 postrotate
  if service tor status > /dev/null; then
   service tor reload > /dev/null
  fi
 endscript
}Ok.....The above is what is says... now what? Adri

Comment: Well, it's normal for it to run. Does quitting arm and startingit again reconnect? If not, then there's nothing in the Tor logs that suggests that's the case and it would be helpful to see what arm reports and what the tor log reports at the time that you cannot connect with arm.